# CSS unrelated element sandwich between other elements

Tags: html, css, z-index

Say that I have a fixed position header (`position: fixed`) at the top-right corner with a sloped `<h1>` element (`tranform: rotate(33.3deg)`). How can I have the main content scroll under the `<h1>` element but over the parent `<header>` element?

I've tried using the straight-forward `z-index` rule, it works in firefox, but not chrome.

So in short:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
header h1 {
    transform: rotate(33.3deg);
    z-index: 9;
}
```

This works in Firefox but in Chrome the child `<h1>` goes under the content along with the parent `<header>`

It is important to sandwich the header around the content in this matter because the `transform: rotate()` rule will create a HUGE box around the transformed child to fit it all inside, rendering hyperlinks unclickable for example.

Comment: "the `transform: rotate()` rule will create a HUGE box around the transformed child." —
This is not entirely true, but I needed to size my parent box manually for other reasons, but I still need to resolve my `z-index` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the behavior you described. When I pasted your code into JSbin (and added some text and background for visual aids, [see demo 1](http://jsbin.com/igodut/4/edit)), the header with the h1 as a whole is displayed above the content  in both Chrome (27 and 30 beta) and Firefox (22). With `z-index: -1` for `header` ([see demo 2](http://jsbin.com/igodut/5/edit)), they both go below the content (but above the body background). It is the expected behavior according to [the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index):

> Each box belongs to one stacking context. Each positioned box in a
>   given stacking context has an integer stack level, which is its
>   position on the z-axis relative other stack levels within the same
>   stacking context. Boxes with greater stack levels are always formatted
>   in front of boxes with lower stack levels. Boxes may have negative
>   stack levels. Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context
>   are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.
>
> The root element forms the root stacking context. Other stacking
>   contexts are generated by any positioned element ... having a computed value of 'z-index' other than
>   'auto'. ... In future levels of CSS, other properties may introduce
>   stacking contexts *(`transform` property [does this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformation-matrix-computation) — Ilya)*.
>
> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking
>      context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most
>      negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including
>      inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned
>      descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least
>      positive first).

So the only solution I can see is to make the 'sandvich' from the sibling elements (or element and pseudo-element), not from the position parent and its child ([see demo 3](http://jsbin.com/igodut/7/edit)).